# Using annotations to control the Redis object serialization?

Tags: java, spring, redis

When you have an object to persist to Redis using Spring Redis Framework, the object is saved to Redis with the key name as given in the object property.

Given:

```
Class Person {

    String name;
    String age;

    //getter and setter.

}
```

Now when this object is serialized and persisted to Redis using

```
redisTemplate.opsForHash().put("PERSON", device.hashCode(), person);
```

the result within Redis looks like

```
PERSON SOMEHASH {name:abc,age:30}
```

It is very convenient to persist the data but would it be more flexible to have annotations to save according to a some naming format the developer want?

Say

```
class Person {

        @(Name = Person_NAME)
        String name;
        @(Name = Person_AGE)
        String age;

        //getter and setter.

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spring Data Redis uses serializers to control how data is represented. Spring Data Redis brings [various](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/redis/docs/current/reference/html/#redis:serializer) serializer implementations.

It looks like you're using the JSON serializer that is built with Jackson2. This means you can control the output by applying [Jackson2 annotations](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.0.2/index.html) to your classes.

```
class Person {

    @JsonProperty(Person_NAME)
    String name;

    @JsonProperty(Person_AGE)
    String age;

    //getter and setter.

}
```